# MVC project complaining it is unable to find Nhibernate.dll version 2.1.0.4000

Tags: nhibernate

In my MVC project, I am trying to use the latest Fluent Nhibernate, and NHibernate.linq.  I am using the Nhibernate.dll that came with the latest Fluent Nhibernate released build.  However, I have only been able to find NHibernate.linq 1.0.

When attempting to run I get the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=2.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's    
manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
0x80131040)
```

I see at SourceForge in the NHibernate project, they have a NHibernate.Linq 2.1.2 version under the NHibernate 2.1.2 project, but if you download this zip, it is empty.

My thoughts is that Linq is referencing the older NHibernate.dll, but how can I get the NHibernate.linq.dll 2.1.2 version?

**There is another question with this same error, and I tried all their suggestions with making sure that all the other NHibernate.dll's are included.  I didn't rebuild the NHibernate.linq project with the same NHibernate.dll that Fluent uses, since I was hoping to get a newer version of NHibernate.linq.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab a build of NHibernate.Linq compatible with NH2.1.2 from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.2GA/NHibernate.Linq-2.1.2-GA-Bin.zip/download

Comment: I mentioned I tried downloading it (2 different PC's) and when attempting to open/extract I get that the file is empty or I will get that it is invalid (Depending on which action).  Are you able to download AND open successfully?

Comment: Windows Explorer doesn't like the zip file for some reason. I was able to open it successfully with 7-Zip (http://www.7-zip.org/) though. FWIW 7-Zip is much, much faster for both compression/extracting than Windows Explorer. WinZip or WinRAR would probably also work just fine.

Comment: @James - That worked, but i noticed that the version of the file is still 1.1.0.1.  By chance is that was you see?

Comment: The extracted file is NHibernate.Linq, Version=1.1.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null and it is referencing NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4. (Grabbed this info from .NET Reflector.) So this will work against NH2.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

As James wrote, you should download the 2.1.2 zip and extract it with 7-Zip. Version number should be 1.1.0.1001.

However... NHibernate 3.0 is about to be released. It contains an integrated Linq provider which is much more complete, powerful and extensible.

I wouldn't use the old provider (which is not completely compatible with the new one) in a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following XML into your Web/App.config file inside the `<configuration>` root tag.

```
   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="AA95F207798DFDB4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.1.4000" newVersion="2.1.2.4000" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```